# How can I successfully map a many to many table in nhibernate with a composedID and still save to it directly?

Tags: nhibernate

I have a bunch of GUID constants in my code for certain tag categories that are important in my application. This is mapped in a simple two column many to many table. I often want to avoid fetching the nhibernate object because all I really need is the GUID and it's already hardcoded. I also noticed it's much quicker and easier to do certain queries with direct table access. So, the goal is to to map those nhibernate many to many tables as a class so they can be read and written to without disrupting nhibernates usage of them in the regular sense; while at the same time using GUIDs for identifiers.

Anyway, I have settled on using a composedID across the two columns nhibernate generates. But there is a problem. **If I use composed ID and make a Category tag object and try to save my TagID and CategoryTag ID directly, TagID gets saved to the CategoryTagID column and CategoryTagID gets saved to the TagID column!**

```
public class CategoryTagMapping : ClassMapping<CategoryTag>
{
    public CategoryTagMapping ()
    {
        Table("CategoryTag");
        /*Id(x => x.ID, map => map.Generator(Generators.Guid));*/
        Property(x => x.CategoryTagID, map => { map.Column("CategoryTagID");});
        Property(x => x.TagID, map => { map.Column("TagID"); });
        ComposedId(p =>
        {
            p.Property(p1 => p1.CategoryTagID, a => a.Column("TagID"));
            p.Property(p1 => p1.TagID, a => a.Column("CategoryTagID"));
        }); 
    }


}
public class CategoryTag 
{
    /*public virtual Guid ID {get;set;}*/
    public virtual Guid CategoryTagID { get; set; }
    public virtual Guid TagID { get; set; }


    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj == null)
            return false;

        var t = obj as CategoryTag;

        if (t == null)
            return false;

        if (this.CategoryTagID == t.CategoryTagID && this.TagID == t.TagID)
            return true;

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return (this.CategoryTagID + "|" + this.TagID).GetHashCode();
    }

}
```

Trying to do this:

```
 CategoryTag A = new CategoryTag { CategoryTagID = Constants.GUID1, TagID = Constants.GUID2 };
```

If I add the ID column by uncommenting the two lines, the saving works properly. But then that breaks the regular usage of the table because mysql can't auto increment the guid field and nhibernate won't generate an ID to go in the ID column.

Anyhow, maybe it's a bug, but maybe there's a workaround. Is there something wrong with the mapping, or the equals/gethashcode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am stupid. The columns are mismatched in the composedID mapping part.